# Map elements of a list of dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this where the key is the node and values are the friends (also nodes) of this node.

```
A= [{'756': ['7403','63708','8070','736','6092',]},
 {'3778':['46798','6812','327811','6838','37591']}]
```

there is another dict where I have the college corresponding to these friends e.g.

```
B=
756:IIMA
7403:Kirori
63708:RamLal
8070:IIMA
736:IIMA
6092:IIMB
```

I want to map the colleges corresponding to the nodes e.g.

```
AB=[{'IIMA': ['Kirori','RamLal','IIMA','IIMA','IIMB',]},
 {'...':['....','....','....','....','....']}]
```

What is the better ways than iterating over each element of A and merging B

Comment: Removed pandas since this is a question about dict to dict mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question was initially labeled pandas, here is a pandas version:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.concat(pd.Series(d) for d in A)  # make a Series of lists
   .apply(pd.Series)                 # transform the list to columns
   .applymap(lambda x: B.get(x,x))   # for each element, if existing, replace with value in B
)
```

output:

```
           0       1       2     3      4
756   Kirori  RamLal    IIMA  IIMA   IIMB
3778   46798    6812  327811  6838  37591
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain this a bit, I am a little new to the space

Comment: @Gupta I added comments. In complement, you should comment each line on the pipe (right before the dot) and uncomment from top to bottom to see the intermediate results

Answer (score 2):

If you have mapping dictionary `B` you can try:

```py
A = [
    {
        "756": [
            "7403",
            "63708",
            "8070",
            "736",
            "6092",
        ]
    },
    {"3778": ["46798", "6812", "327811", "6838", "37591"]},
]

B = {
    "756": "IIMA",
    "7403": "Kirori",
    "63708": "RamLal",
    "8070": "IIMA",
    "736": "IIMA",
    "6092": "IIMB",
}

AB = [
    {B.get(k, k): [B.get(vv, vv) for vv in v] for k, v in d.items()} for d in A
]
print(AB)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"IIMA": ["Kirori", "RamLal", "IIMA", "IIMA", "IIMB"]},
    {"3778": ["46798", "6812", "327811", "6838", "37591"]},
]
```

---

EDIT: Solution without dict-/list- comprehensions:

```py
AB = []
for d in A:
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in B:
            k = B[k]

        new_lst = []
        for vv in v:
            if vv in B:
                vv = B[vv]
            new_lst.append(vv)

        new_d[k] = new_lst
    AB.append(new_d)
```

Comment: Hi Can you explain this a bit. Are you using dictionary comprehension. Would be great if you can add any references that i can go through

Comment: @Gupta It's combination of dictionary- and list- comprehensions. I'll update the answer with classic for-loop approach.